# Add cell/data to the top of UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to create a simple chat application for iOS. It currently looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the order that the messages is displayed, i.e. display the latest message over the older messages. My current implementation looks like this:

```
// Datasource for the tableView
messages  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [...]
    // messageTextView is a contentView subView.
    messageTextView.text = [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [...]

- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender
{
    [messages addObject:messageField.text];
    messageField.text = @"";
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    /*
     I have tried the implementation below, but I always got an exception.
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
     NSIndexPath *path1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]; 
     NSArray * indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path1,nil]; 
     [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray 
     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
     */
```

}

Any tips on how to do this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple you need to insert the new `UITableViewCell` at the 0 index. Also modify your Datasource otherwise your app will crash. Below I show how to modify your `UITableView`. Modifying your datasource is easy.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

What you are essentially doing here is inserting the new chat message cell at the 0th index position. You could use a nice animation effect to make it appear or fade in.

There are various animations that you can use here-

```
UITableViewRowAnimationBottom
UITableViewRowAnimationFade
UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle
UITableViewRowAnimationNone
UITableViewRowAnimationRight
UITableViewRowAnimationTop
```

Comment: Thank you. Got it to work thanks to your and Himanshu A Jadav:s answer's. Did as you suggested with indexPath and I changed addObject to insertObject as Himanshu A Jadav:s suggested.

Comment: in what ways does one need to modify their data source?

Answer (score 6):

You can try.

```
[messages insertObject:messageField.text atIndex:0];
```

instead of `[messages addObject:messageField.text];`.

Comment: Great tip for inserting at certain index!

Comment: Really helpful solution.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution

Define array like this

```
   var arrMessage = [AnyObject]()
```

and Button Action

```
 @IBAction func btnSendMessageTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    arrMessage.insert(txtTypeMessage.text!, atIndex: 0)
    txtTypeMessage.text = ""
    self.tblMessage.reloadData()

}
```